# How does introducing a new Black Body affect another Black Body ( which was in steady state )

Tags: radiation, thermal-radiation

> The shell of a space station is a blackened sphere in which a temperature $T = 500 K$ is maintained due to the operation of the appliances of the station which always supply heat at constant rate. If the station is enveloped by a thin spherical black screen of nearly the same radius as the radius of the shell of the station then the new steady state temperature (approx.) of the shell of the station will be (use $2^{1/4} =1.19$) :-

My method of approach was that :
When there was only one Black body and it was in Steady State , lets name that as Case 1.
And when the next black body comes in ,( and is not in steady state ) lets name it Case 2 , and when everything reaches steady state again , lets call it Case 3 .

Since the two black bodies will finally come to steady state and the first black body already has a constant source of heat supply inside, it has to emit the same amount of energy it is getting from its internal heat supplier. And this is just like Case 1 .
So the $P_{\text{emitted in Case 1}}=P_{\text{emitted in Case 3}}$
(where P is the power emitted )

Now using the formula $P=e\sigma A T^4$  we have

$e\sigma AT_1^4=e\sigma A T_2^4$ ( where T_1 is the temperature in Case 1 and T_2 is of Case 3,and A is of the first black body)

and since $e$,$A$,$\sigma$ are all same for the blackbody in case 1 and in case 3 , so I concluded that the temperature must be same .

But it is not .The answer to this question is $594K$

Comment: Hint: There is a particular difference between the emission of the shell and the emission of the space station. The instruction to use $2^{1/4}=1.19$ is a hint in itself, too...

Comment: But then the space station emission is ( coming from ) inside the first black body so it has to absorb all the radiation and then emit . Are you trying to say that ( some part) of the space stations emission will reach the second black body ( directly , without being intercepted by the first black body ) ?. Also yes the $2^{1/4}=1.19$ is indeed a hint but  couldnt understand the logic enough to use it .

Comment: Think a bit more about the emission of the second black body